# Stripe "No such token: " error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, stripe-payments

my stripe account is configured with `test`. and using `test` keys into my laravel application.

While posting, i am creating new `stripe user` if not exist like this,

```
Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('constants.features.stripe.secret'));
$token = $input['_token']; 

$customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
            "description" => "#{$user->id} / {$user->username} / {$user->email}",
            "source" => $token,
            "email" => $user->email
        ));
```

And creating charge like this,

```
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
                "amount" => '5000',
                "currency" => "gbp",
                "customer" => $customer->id,
                "description" => 'description',
                "statement_descriptor" => strtoupper("test desc")
            ));
```

But it return error `Stripe_InvalidRequestError No such token:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_token` input from Laravel is the CSRF token. This is not the token you should be passing to stripe in the `source` field. The token in the `source` field should be the token generated by the stripe.js library which allows you to identify a customers credit card without actually seeing the card details.

The stripe documentation explains how you should be handling this https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js